# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3

Tags: python, json, excel, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am using python 2.7 to read a JSON file. My code is:

```
import json
from json import JSONDecoder
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/json'
print path

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.dirname(path+'/json')):
    for f in files:  
        if f.lower().endswith((".json")):
            fp=open(root + '/'+f)
            data = fp.read()
            print data.decode('utf-8')
```

But I got the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 72: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: JSON is defined to use UTF-8 but a lone 0xF3 byte is not valid in a UTF-8 multibyte sequence.  Your file is not valid UTF-8.  A common workaround is to force a different encoding, commonly `'latin-1'`, but this will basically create incorrect results instead.  If you know the actual encoding of the input, by all means use that.

Comment: See also the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for background and troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Why do you add `/json`, then strip it off with `os.path.dirname()` only to add it back again?

Comment: If add that json, It walk into json Directory.

Comment: Is there way to find the encoding , by reading the file properties or by any means.

Comment: Unfortunately there’s no generic way of guessing the encoding of a file, and I don’t think JSON provides a way to specify this information in a header. Anyway, you should note that JSON files have to be encoded in unicode, and by default in utf-8 ([source](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1)), if they’re not in unicode, the person who created those JSONs did some pretty ugly mistake.

Comment: But in practice, you can often deduce the correct encoding, especially if you have sample text which you know what it's supposed to represent. Maybe see also https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html

Comment: Take a look at [`chardet`](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/). It has a tool for detecting encodings. It's far from perfect, but frequently provides useful information.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your file is not encoded in UTF-8, and the error occurs at the `fp.read()` line. You must use:

```
import io
io.open(filename, encoding='latin-1')
```

And the correct, not platform-dependent usage for joining your paths is:

```
os.path.join(root, f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. But I have many files like this. I can`t assure all files are in 'latin'.

Comment: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function- Error I got

Comment: The encoding keyword is specific to Python 3. A portable solution is to use `FileIO.open()`

Comment: My bad, I didn’t notice this was a Python 2 question. You simply need to use  `io.open()` though...

Comment: Yes, It works when I gave io.open(finame, encoding="latin-1")

Comment: Is there any to way to find the file encoding?

Comment: Please refer to the comments from tripleee and myself on your original post.