# Trying to read csv with special characters from AWS S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Im trying to read a csv from my bucket on S3 using AWS Lambda, but the csv have special characters from brazillian portuguese alphabet.

```
def rentabilidade_sintetica():

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_name = "bucket-my"
s3_file_name = "historico/Rentabilidade Sintetica1.csv"
resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_name)
df_s3_data = pd.read_csv(resp['Body'], sep=';')
```

Because of that, i get the following error:

"errorMessage": "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4: unexpected end of data",

"errorType": "UnicodeDecodeError",

When I changed the special characters in the csv files, the code worked.

So I tried to specify the encoding parameter at read_csv:

```
df_s3_data = pd.read_csv(resp['Body'], sep=';', encoding='cp860')
```

but it gave me the same error.

Do you have any other method to read this?

Comment: that is strange, utf-8 should work fine with Portuguese. Did you check if it is indeed UTF-8/ properly encoded/decoded with a debugger? Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996289/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xf3) for instance

Comment: The CSV was not UTF-8, I save it again with the porper format and worked despite the special characters. Thanks.