# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 3118: invalid start byte Simple text file

Tags: python

I'm following a sentiment analysis tutorial in which he provided the files to use. These are simple .txt files and when he runs the same code it works fine. But when I run it I get the below error.

```
with open("positive.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        analysis = TextBlob(line)
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            pos_correct += 1
        pos_count +=1

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4645: invalid continuation byte
```

How can we have the same code and same file but I get this error and he does not?

Here is a link to the file if this helps. https://pythonprogramming.net/static/downloads/short_reviews/

Update to my question. I was trying this on my Mac when I ran into the issue. Tried it on my Windows PC and it works fine. Any ideas what the difference would be? Did everything the same.

Comment: You may need to convert "positive.txt" to the `utf-8` encoding, or specify the encoding of the 'positive.txt" file.

Comment: I don't get an error when I read the file and just count the lines instead of doing the processing you're doing. Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of the error/traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146) you are getting.

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996289/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xf3) helps.

Comment: See also https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the file is not encoded in `utf-8`. Could you try open the file using [io.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with `latin-1` encoding instead?

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import io

# dummy variables initialization
pos_correct = 0
pos_count = 0

with io.open("positive.txt", encoding='latin-1') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        analysis = TextBlob(line)
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            pos_correct += 1
        pos_count +=1
```